# Airflow to BigQueryt data load taking forever

Tags: mysql, python, architecture, google-bigquery

Im currently working as a junior data engineer. My main job right now is to move data from a DB in MYSQL (which gets updated every few minutes via webhooks) and send it to BigQuery as frequently as posible using Airflow, as this is our main DB for later analyzing data with power BI.

The problem is that the bigger tables (which only have ~ 1000 rows) take about 2 hours to load to BQ, and thus making this impossible to scale, I can´t imagine what will happen in the future when only the deltas are 10000 rows each...

This works using pandas and SQLAlchemy by extracting data as a dataframe and using "to_sql" method passing all the BQ connection parameters.

I am already uploading only incrementals/delta, that is not the problem.

Do you have any advice? Is Airflow the right tool for this? I´ve been searching for solutions for weeks but couldn´t find anything.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can quickly build a CSV file for one table.  How many tables do you need to copy?  Are there any `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns?

Surely bigquery has a way to load a CSV file.

I would expect the two steps to take less than 1 minute (maybe less than 1 second) per table.

"as fast as possible"  Make a script that loops.

Do not use `cron` or equivalent (Airflow??) unless you include some mechanism to keep a second copy from running before the first copy ends.  I think it is simpler to just loop.

I don't know what Airflow is, but it sounds like it is getting in the way.

1000 rows is trivial.  Even in a worst case, I would expect only a few seconds to dump or load.  Please time the two parts -- to find out whether the dump is slow or the load is.

How many tables?

Comment: Airflow is a scheduler, just does what you tell it to do periodically. So passing the data to csv first is faster than a dataframe? The idea is that this runs every hour to keep data updated/fresh in BIgQuery ,but im afraid this wont scale if our biggest table rn is 1000 rows (will be much bigger in the future

Comment: @Ayrton - I made several changes in my Answer.  Also, what are the parameters/configuration you are using for Airflow?

Comment: Hi Rick! I meant as frequent as posible, in order to have data fresh of last 15 minutes or something, so Airflow running every 15 minutes would be great, I dont think if a loop would help in this case. Today we have 30 tables, but the process runs in parallel for everyone of those. What do you mean by Airflow config btw? We are using chunksize of 10.000 if that helps

Comment: @Ayrton - Some day, the last 15 minutes will have twice as much data. And take longer than 15 minutes to process.  Will Airflow realise that the previous run is not finished?

Comment: Yeah, its not like it executes functions after a certain time period, it checks if the last run has finished before executing again